# Delay of 15 hours in Air India Flight from New York to Delhi

Tags: delays, compensation, air-india

I am supposed to travel by Air India International flight from New York to Delhi on 7th July (Departure time 12:05 pm)  but i have received a mail from them saying that now the flight has been rescheduled for 8th July (Departure time 03:45 am) and the delay is for than 15 hours.
Kindly let me know what steps can i take to get refunfd from them regarding hotel and food as all my bookings were till 7th July only.

Comment: What research have you done up to now? Have you read the T&C of your ticket? Contacted the airline or searched its web site for information about delays? Do you have travel insurance that covers you for a delay of 15+ hours?

Comment: _rescheduled_ is quite different from _delayed_. Which is it?